# What does しょっぽい mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I heard this the other day, and I can't find it in my dictionary. From the context, it seemed to be used with the meaning of "disappointing," or "a let-down."

Comment: Could you have misheard しょぼい ?

Comment: It's possible, but I've never heard that one either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's しょぼい too. You are close about the meaning. 
http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%BC%E3%81%84

Comment: +1 For it being しょぼい

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm more familiar with the adverb しょんぼり, meaning *"down in the dumps, downhearted, blue"*.  Looking into this some, I've discovered related terms しょぼくれる, しょぼしょぼ, しょぼん（と）, and しょぼたれる, all with the same basic meaning.

From this, I would guess that しょっぽい is part of this same group.  The っぽい ending is an adjectivizing suffix meaning *"-ish"*, so presumably しょっぽい would mean *"bluish (of mood), kinda depressed or depressing"*.

#### UPDATE

As others have noted in the comments to the question, the asker's しょっぽい may be a mis-hearing or alteration of しょぼい, itself derived as the simple adjectivization of the root しょぼ + い.